# Python -- elegant dict comp where keys/values comes from sync'd lists?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary with two entries:

```
"triggers":[1, 4, 5, 9], 
"actions":[2, [1, 12, 13, 14], [1, 12, 13, 14], [3, 12, 13]]
```

Triggers correspond to actions -- so 1 corresponds to 2, 4 corresponds to the list [1,12,13,14], etc.  I am trying to create a dictionary in which I flatten this and correspond the numbers to these two dictionaries:

```
ALARM_TRIGGER_EVENTS = {1: "SENSOR OPEN",
                        2: "MOTION DETECTED",
                        ...etc}
ALARM_ACTION_EVENTS = {1: "S-SOUND SIREN",
                       2: "SOUND BEEP",
                       ...etc}
```

So my ultimate dictionary should flatten the first two but replace the numbers with the corresponding event names in the last two dictionaries, something like this:

```
{"SENSOR OPEN":"SOUND BEEP", etc}
```

So far, I've been able to flatten the first two with this:

```
{trigger:self.alarmInfo["actions"][i] for i, trigger in \
    enumerate(self.alarmInfo["triggers"])}
```

(for reference, self.alarmInfo is a dictionary of the first set of lists)

So, two questions: 1) is there a more elegant way to accomplish the dictionary comprehension I just posted and 2) is there an elegant way to transform the numbers to the values so I end up with the preferred dictionary look I posted above?  I keep thinking of ways, but they end up being incredibly hard to read and ugly.  Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using `ALARM_TRIGGER_EVENTS` and `ALARM_ACTION_EVENTS`?

Comment: So, the first entry of `1:2` would correspond to `"SENSOR OPEN":"SOUND BEEP"`, the second entry of `4:[1,12,13,14]` would correspond to `"NOT THERE":["S-SOUND SIREN", "NOT THERE", "ALSO NOT THERE", "AGAIN NOT THERE"]`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: correct -- I left out a bunch so I didn't have a 2 page question

Comment: @thefourtheye: nowhere, yet -- that's where the second question comes in -- turning the flattened result into a dict of the strings that correspond to the ints in the first lists

Comment: @wim: I figured it out using zip -- if you post an answer with that I can accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> d = {
...     'actions': [2, [1, 12, 13, 14], [1, 12, 13, 14], [3, 12, 13]],
...     'triggers': [1, 4, 5, 9],
... }
>>> d_map = dict(zip(d['triggers'], d['actions']))
>>> d_map = {k: [v] if isinstance(v, int) else v for k,v in d_map.items()}
>>> d_map
{1: [2], 4: [1, 12, 13, 14], 5: [1, 12, 13, 14], 9: [3, 12, 13]}
```

Now you can write the comprehension:

```
{TRIGGERS[k]: [ACTIONS(v) for v in vs] for k,vs in d_map.items()}
```